# how to get the safearea thickness?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want place an image in the top of the screen.

so I tried to get the top safearea insets.

```
var safeArea=On<Xamarin.Forms.PlateformConfiguaration.iOS>().SafeAreaInsets();
safeArea.Top=-safeArea.Top;
Image.Margin=safeArea;
```

but all the safeArea properties is 0.

hot to get the right thickness?

Comment: Your code works fine on my side . Where did you call the method? You can provide a sample which contains the issue and I will check it .

Comment: Hi @LucasZhang-MSFT I call it in the OnAppeared method does it wrong?

Comment: You can check my answer , I call the code in `onAppearing` and it works fine. So if my answer still doesn't work ,you can provide your sample .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly , **SafeArea** is available after iOS 11.0 ,So you should check the version of iOS before you want to get it .

I suggest you can use **DependencyService**

#### in Forms ,create the Interface

```
public interface IGetSafeArea
{
  double GetSafeAreaTop();
  double GetSafeAreaBottom();
}
```

#### in iOS

```
using UIKit;

using xxx;

namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class GetSafeArea : IGetSafeArea
    {
        public double GetSafeAreaBottom()
        {
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0))
            {
                UIWindow window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow();              
                var bottomPadding = window.SafeAreaInsets.Bottom;
                return bottomPadding;
            }
            return 0;
        }

        public double GetSafeAreaTop()
        {
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0))
            {
                UIWindow window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow();
                var topPadding = window.SafeAreaInsets.Top;
                return topPadding;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And invoke the method as you want

```
var top = DependencyService.Get<IGetSafeArea>().GetSafeAreaTop();
```

Comment: I did it but it tells me object reference not set to  an instance of an object.

Comment: with the code "DependencyService.Get<IGetSafeArea>()",It seems can not get the interface. I created the method in ios and android

Comment: You should create the Interface in Forms and call it in contentpage .

Comment: Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Comment: Yes I created the interface in Forms and called it in contentpage.but it did failed.I do not know why

Comment: Share your sample .And I can check it on my side